# Как перенаправлять пользователя, если возникла ошибка 500?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Возник вопрос - иногда на сайте могут возникать ошибки http(404, 401, 500 и т.д.), как можно показывать пользователю вместо "страница недоступна", другую страницу, где будет описана сама ошибка (типо такая страница-заглушка)?

пробовал в htacces:

`ErrorDocument 500 /error?error=500`

но это не работает, показывает "страница недоступна"

Comment: `ErrorDocument 404 https://ваш_сайт/404.html` - ссылка на конкретный файл - работает.

Comment: А `ErrorDocument 500 /error.php?error=500` нет?)

Comment: нет, 500 не работает. а вот 404, 401 работает

Comment: nginx используется?

Comment: @JarryRoxwell если .htaccess используется, очевидно же, что апачи)

Comment: [Нашел тут статью](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-apache-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-14-04), которая все описывает, пробовал такое решение?

Comment: @AidarSaifutdinov нет, не очевидно, они могут использоваться вместе, да еще и по разному

Comment: Есть мнение, возможно ошибочное, что 5xx ошибки, те, что на стороне сервера, могут и вовсе не отдавать результата. А значит php-файл, в котором вы желаете сделать обработку - может не выполниться и ничего не вернуть. В этом случае нужно явно прописывать путь к конкретному файлу, где и будет описан код ошибки.

Comment: На сайте сделайте `redirect`. Имейте класс исключений.